# Why use both className and classes

Tags: material-ui

Please forgive my probably simple question :-)

Just wondering why the examples use className and classes, for example :

```
<Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
          [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
        })}
        classes={{
          paper: clsx({
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
          }),
        }}
        open={open}
      >
```

thank you in advance for your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`className` is equal to `class`(as in HTML) in React. Because we write everting in .js file, class is a reserved keyword so the creators of React made it called `className`.

`classes` is your object which contains your styles.
You define classes as like below.
Example;

```
// Banner.js
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Box, Button } from '@material-ui/core/'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  bannerBackground: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }
})
export default function Banner() {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Box className={classes.bannerBackground}>
      <Button variant='contained' color='primary'>
        Start a project
      </Button>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

And when React compiles your code it will understand which style you used because you passed `classes.bannerBackground` object which contains your styles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just wondering why the example uses both at the same time, can I just use either className or classes, just like your example ?

Comment: If you use it like this <Box className={classes.bannerBackground}></Box> then it should work fine.